# mozilla firefox does not work normally

Tags: android, html, firefox, galaxy, android-2.2-froyo

I have an application that use mozilla browser for samsung galaxy tab 7 (android froyo). But the browser does not work normally, it's running very slow, so my application does not work good. I tried to use another galaxy tab with same specification, and the result is not different. Then i tried to another galaxy tab with different specification, and the browser ran normally.

I used html 5 in my web aplication.

What is the problem of mozilla firefox in samsung galaxy tab 7?

What can i do to solve the problem?

Comment: Which other browsers did you test? Which devices besides that galaxy tab 7 did you test? What is the code that runs slowly? If you let us guessing, you can't get proper answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen due to two following reasons:
a) Mozilla Firefox may be running and it is not responding at all
b) ~/.mozilla directory is corrupted while updating or installing an extension

First see if Firefox is running or not by typing following command:
$ ps aux | grep firefox

If a process is running, kill it by typing:
$ kill 3174
Now try to start Firefox